# How to specify tags for scalar summary of unknown shape in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Let's imagine the following situation:

```
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
c = tf.concat(1, [a, b])

tf.scalar_summary(tags, c)
```

In this situation, the actual shape of the `a` and `b` placeholders will only be set when running the session and feeding concrete data to the placeholders.

However, according to API the shape of tags needs to match the shape of `c`. How can that be achieved?

Comment: This isn't possible with the current API because there are no string manipulation ops in TensorFlow at present and (as you pointed in your comment on my deleted answer) a later call to `tf.merge_all_summaries()` will raise an error if the tags are not unique. We have been experimenting with some ops for string manipulation internally and will include some variant of these in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That's what I suspected.